# Matching ActiveRecord::Store columns in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model named User, I am storing a hash to the user model in attribute params. I have declared this column as store in my user model without any accessor,I am accessing it as `@user.params`, while saving data to database it works quite fine. However, I have to retrieve data by certain criteria.

Say I have stored a user Object with params field as { checked: true }
and Other by { checked: true }

Now I have to retrieve user having params: { checked: true}

The query I am using is:

```
User.where(params: {"checked" => true});
```

This is Throwing Error as:

```
INTERNAL ERROR!!! SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: params.checked: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "params"."checked" = 't'
```

I searched a ton about comparing two store fields in database but have not found related stuff.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you provide some more details of this "params" field - is it a serialized field?  What is actually stored in the database for this field for the object in your example?

Comment: @sharvy  I am able to access it without any Issue

Comment: @max yes it is a serialized filed I have used active record store, Please have a look: [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

Comment: what's your `params` column type?

Comment: @Liyali it's column type in database is Text

Comment: Did you try using `LIKE` ?

Comment: Do we have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  scope :score, -> {
    where :score -> true
  }
end
```

controller..

```
@users = params[:checked]? ? User.score : User.all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can't do the query in a straight forward way. `store` is just a `Hash` which gets serialized and deserialized upon save and load. When you are using `store`, you're pretty much limited to loading and saving the data.

You can try using `LIKE` (can't assure if it will work or not):

```
User.where('params LIKE ?', '%checked: true%')
```

I suggest not to use `store` (serialized) for any data you need to query on.

*PostgreSQL can store and search hashes/json - check out `hstore`.*